# Python enum like construction with metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason, on a Sunday morning I felt like I needed the following for a scientific library I'm writing:

```
class PolarityType(type):
    """Metaclass to construct polarity types. Supports conversion to float and int."""
    def __float__(cls):
        return int(cls)

    def __int__(cls):
        return cls.P


class Polarity(metaclass=PolarityType):
    """Base class to build polarity."""
    P = 0


class PositivePolarity(Polarity):
    """Positive polarity."""
    P = 1


class NegativePolarity(Polarity):
    """Negative polarity."""
    P = -1

>>> float(NegativePolarity)
>>> -1.0
```

Basically instead of passing arguments like `polarity='POSITIVE'` and checking strings, and also because I'm using type hints, I wanted it to be strongly typed and I wrote the above code.

Does it make sense, is there a much easier/cleaner/better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: is there a reason you cant just use regular ints for this? that is, `NegativePolarity = -1`

Comment: It felt more robust to use the type system, plus, I can type hint it.

Comment: I've seen people go one step up the hierarchy and treat types as values in Haskell, but in Python? It doesn't even have a proper type checker. Not sure I understand the motivation, but if you want to type-hint a function parameter to be, say `NegativePolarity`, how is that different from not passing this parameter at all, since you know that polarity is negative?

Comment: @Norrius for your second question: I would type hint it as `PolarityType` for example `def foo(polarity: PolarityType = PositivePolarity): pass` .

Comment: Huh, okay, that looks sound (and mypy agrees). To avoid metaclasses, you could also define something like `PositivePolarity = Polarity(1)`, and then use it as `def f(p: Polarity = PositivePolarity): pass`, which is very similar to enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution works, but is there a special reason not to use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)?

```
import enum

class Polarity(enum.Enum):
    POSITIVE: float = 1.0
    NEGATIVE: float = -1.0

    def __float__(cls):
        return self.value

    def __int__(cls):
        return int(self.value)

print(Polarity.NEGATIVE, type(Polarity.NEGATIVE))
# Polarity.NEGATIVE <enum 'Polarity'>

print(type(Polarity.NEGATIVE.value), Polarity.NEGATIVE.value)
# <class 'float'> -1.0

print(type(float(Polarity.NEGATIVE)), float(Polarity.NEGATIVE))
# <class 'float'> -1.0
```

Comment: Looks great. I admit I had never used `enum` and forgot about it.